# Как сделать фокус для окон? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Искал много, нужного не нашел! Помогите! Есть несколько окон с общим селектором ".window-class" и второй селектор уже уникальный. Все созданные окна могу перемещаться по рабочему столу, и задача стоит в том, что нужно сделать переключение фокуса между окнами. Например при нажатии на окно, оно должно стать выше всех, а остальные окна ниже по Z-index, аналогично можно видеть в Windows(e) при нажатии на приложение при условии что второе тоже находится открытым на рабочем столе. Код на JQuery тоже подойдет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На скриншоте мышка перемещает и нажимает мышкой на окошко c названием "Seo construct", вот оно должно быть теперь выше чем "Добро пожаловать в Web OS"!!! Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так, а если при выборе определено окна. Навешивать на него соответсвующий класс, с  наивысшим индексом. Ну, а остальным окнам которые на рабочем столе делать индекс (n-1).

Comment: Да, вот именно! Так и задумывалось изначально, сам метод который я использовал почему то не работает! Объясняю.
При клике на окно, узнается селектор (Уникальный) например "window_app_piskel" или  "window_app_browser" он уникален и у всех разный, но соединяет их в одно целое общий селектор "window-class". Я через цикл for искал все элементы окон с их селекторами и сверял, что если во время поиска селектор окна не равен селектору на который кликнули, поставить ему z-index: - 1, а если селектор совпал с тем на которого кликнули то поставить z-index: 1; (Выше). Не знаю как правильно написать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла данная вставка на **JQuery**!

```
// Указываем фокус для окна поверх другого или ниже
    $(".window-class").click(function() {
        $(".window-class").not(this).css("z-index", "1")
    $(this).css("z-index", "2")
    });
```